# How to parse a string separated by space when there is space inside the subelements?

Tags: java, regex

The input string is like this, each element is separated by a single space:

`"Fri, 23 May 2014 10:17:54 -0400 (EDT)" "This is a subject" ((NIL NIL \"10013001906\" \"domainname\"))`,

the output should be an array of String:

`a[0] = "Fri, 23 May 2014 10:17:54 -0400 (EDT)",a[1] = "This is a subject",a[2] = ((NIL NIL \"10013001906\" \"domainname\"))`.

I got a java version regular expression work and here is the example code:

```
private static void parseWholeEnvelope(){
String envelope = "\"Tue, 29 Sep 2009 12:00:00 +0100\" \"IMAPenvelope   test\""
     +" ((\"Test User1\" NIL \"testuser\" \"imaptest.net\"))"
     +" ((\"Test User2\" NIL \"testuser\" \"imaptest.net\"))"
     +" ((\"Test User3\" NIL \"testuser\" \"imaptest.net\"))"
     +" ((\"IMAP User\" NIL \"imap\" \"imaptest.net\")"
     +  " (\"Another User\" NIL \"a.n.other\" \"imaptest.net\"))"
     +" NIL NIL NIL"
     +" \"<4A671940.7030003@imaptest.net>\"";
String pattern4Envelope = "((\\((\\([^\\)]+\\)\\s*)+\\))|(\"[^\"]*\")|(NIL|\"[^\"]* \"))+?";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(pattern4Envelope, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(envelope);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Found the text \"" + matcher.group()
    + "\" starting at " + matcher.start()
    + " index and ending at index " + matcher.end());
}
}
```

Comment: You strings are not separated by a space they are delimited with unescaped double quotes. Do you want to use regex to split, parsing is n't particular difficullt, though waht language you are using would be helpful...

Comment: Does your string always have this pattern? If so, matching on ( and ) would help you in determining the start and end of each string.

Answer (score 0):

Somethihg that you can use for this particular instance is:

```
Regex reg = new Regex("\" [\"(]");
```

Or whatever you would use for your language.  This one looks for a quote mark followed by a space and then followed by either another quote or an open parenthetical.

The only problem you'll encounter is that it will splice the closing quote from the first, the closing and opening quotes from the second, and the open paren from the third.  Unfortunately, with my limited knowledge, I can't do any better for you.

Yields:

```
string[0] = "Fri, 23 May 2014 10:17:54 -0400 (EDT)
string[1] = This is a subject
string[2] = (NIL NIL \"10013001906\" \"domainname\"))
```

Escape sequences and quotes not used to simplify output.